# Can't extend root partition with unallocated space

Tags: debian, root, ext4, gparted

I'm trying to extend my root partition with the unallocated space but it seems like the unallocated space didn't exist. When I reinstalled the system I had two different Free Spaces, one with 32GB and other with 19GB but wasn't able to fix them in the same partition.

I've tried with the solutions in other posts with no result...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the root partition the one of the system currently running? Or are you running `gparted` from a live CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're running gparted from your Linux-distro, and that means that some of you're partitions - including your root-partition - are in use (that's what that icon looking like a numerical keypad or whatever means).  You can't move or resize a partition your actually actively using (which you here are).

Try running gparted from a "live"-DVD.  It may use your swap-partition, but should leave the root-partition alone.  When it's not in active use, you should be able to resize it into your free-space (will probably take a long while, since stuff will have to be moved too).

(Could add that the "mother-program" - parted - may be a bit less restrictive than gparted... but then again, the interface is more difficult and it's easier to make a mistake.)